# How do you access keyboard script in Android?

Tags: keyboard, key

My Android phone was maliciously hacked and keys on the keyboard were disabled, making it impossible to type passwords. Is this possible to fix? Can I do it? or do you need to be an expert?

Comment: Not sure if this would help but I bumped into this article last night. Check [this](https://www.androidpit.com/samsung-galaxy-s6-swiftkey-keyboard-hack-exploit) out.